# Change Vim Output of '$' when running code in R

Tags: vim

I'm using GNU Screen to run R code from Vim. When I try to run code containing the dollar sign character `$`, it is sent from Vim to R as `\$`.

Is there a way to change this in the .vimrc file so inline `$` characters are sent to the R window as `$` rather than `\$`?

R and Vim are connected through the following mapping in the `.vimrc` file:

```
map <C-L> "kyy:echo system("screen -S $STY -p R -X stuff ".escape(shellescape(@k),"$"))<CR>j

vmap <C-L> "xy:echo system("screen -S $STY -p R -X stuff ".escape(shellescape(@x."\n"),"$"))<CR>j
```

(I use Cntr-L to send the current line or highlighted code block to my R window, titled "R")

Comment: Please be more specific about your procedure. How does screen, R, and Vim tie together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are explicitly escaping the `$` characters by calling `escape(shellescape(@k),"$")`. `shellescape(@k)` does not escape `$` characters, so just remove the call to `escape()`:

```
map <C-L> "kyy:echo system("screen -S $STY -p R -X stuff ".shellescape(@k))<CR>j

vmap <C-L> "xy:echo system("screen -S $STY -p R -X stuff ".shellescape(@x."\n"))<CR>j
```

Comment: That's what I get for using code before I understand it. Thanks!

Comment: This is interesting. But I get all the new lines stripped from both commands. The yanked line just gets echoed without "enter" in R. For visual selection all lines get pasted as one line.